# Npm command not found in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

Please tell me how i can solve it. Iam using window 7 32 bit:

[image]

Comment: Did you install node.js?

Comment: I suddenly have this issue too after X months of a stable setup. I usually run scripts by clicking them in the VS Code panel "NPM SCRIPTS", however I get the error `/usr/bin/bash: line 1: npm: command not found`. Instead I have to manually type commands in terminal (same folder !?) and everything works: `npm run dev`, for instance.

Answer (score 47):

On Mac OS , I switched to the zsh and got this fixed. These following steps fixed the issue :

1. On your VsCode in Mac : `shift + command + P` .
2. On the Prompt > type :  `Terminal: Select Default Profile` , then "Click it". Note, as you type you will find this option in the auto-complete .
3. Click the option for zsh or your desired shell.
4. Restart VSCode .

now `npm` will work in your vscode terminal.

[image]

Comment: Same on Linux. And completely restarting VSCode is actually necessary, `Ctrl+Shift+P` → `Reload window` is not enough. We can show this by adding for instance `echo $(date) started >> /home/<your-name>/start.txt` in your `.zshrc`, where NVM is loaded. You'll see that it's only when VSCode starts that `.zshrc` gets sourced, not when a terminal is opened, or when we do `Reload window`.

Comment: why make an app that works, if you can force people to google how to fix the most basic feature? ‍♂️ thanks, that worked - and yes, must restart VSCode

Comment: He said he is using "window 7 32 bit"

Answer (score 37):

By default, Visual Studio Code runs shell commands like `npm` in a loginless shell. If you installed NVM, Visual Studio Code may have no indication where to find `npm` to run it.

Put the following lines are in `.bash_profile`: (Note: Not `.bashrc`.)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Add this setting to `settings.json`:

`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]`

Comment: Donno why this was downvoted, but this answer actually helped me with the same problem (ZSH instead of Bash) in Linux while migrating from VS Code to Codium.

Comment: Note that it can be .zprofile instead of .bash_profile

Comment: so why does it have to be in bash_profile and not bashrc?

Comment: I had the `nvm` script in both `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc`. Had to add the `-l` option AND restart VSCode.

Comment: @FelipeCenteno I'm guessing it has something to do with the "loginless shell" and the fact that `.bashrc` is a local config

Comment: True answer for me. This happens to me on a new work mac with now setups. It is actually required on the brew page for doing so after your installation. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nvm

Answer (score 22):

I too had this issue.
To solve this follow the below steps.
Make sure you have npm installed 
 - go to command prompt & type *npm -v*
 - if a version comes out it's installed, else go to https://nodejs.org/en/ and download same.
Then come to vs code and set deafult shell to cmd.
to do so,
 - Press Ctrl+Shift+P and type Select Default Shell
 - Select Command Prompt.
 - Press Ctrl+`
 - Type *npm -v* and see npm works. :)

Comment: this worked for me, simply put my vscode was using bash instead of cmd prompt... interesting it flipped from cmd to bash after an install which caught me off guard

Comment: The switching shells helped me. Make sure to restart VS code too if you had it opened during the install or it still won't work!

Comment: This answer helped me, except Ctrl+Shift+P didn't work for me (on mac).  Instead I was able to switch by doing this:  1.  In menu choose Terminal > New Terminal.  2.  Click the plus (+) symbol at the top of the new terminal which next to the word "bash" and change it to something other than "bash."  In my case, "zsh."

Comment: This worked for me - except that there is no longer "Select Default Shell" in vscode anymore... There is "Select Default Profile"... and then you can set it to either cmd or powershell and one other option

Comment: After following the steps, no matter how many times I restarted VScode, I did not get the issue resolved until I rebooted my machine.

Answer (score 15):

I got this error after having just installed nodejs/npm, and the way i resolved, while still being able to use git bash terminal in vscode was to simply restart my computer (I hadn't done this after node installation).

Comment: Ha! Thank you! This worked! node and npm were working in terminals outside vscode but for some reason not in VSCode's internal terminal, I restarted and they work!

Comment: The config for my bash terminal 'inside vscode' hasn't changed (default setting) and I tried this and it worked... I should've dive into this at first, oh my one hour.

Answer (score 6):

If you just installed your node while your VScode was running. Restart your vscode it should start working.

Comment: This was it for me, I tried reloading the window and that did not do it but just closing and reopening did it on windows, thx!

Answer (score 4):

As you're aware, you can configure your environment variables in windows at 2 levels.

1. At user level
2. At system level

When VS code is started, it picks the variables in path at a user level and not at system level because you haven't run the application as **Administrator**.

[image: Environment Variables]
Just copy-paste your node path from **System Variables** to **User Variables**

This does the trick for windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On mac, I switched the default shell from bash to zsh and it fixed the issue.

Comment: OP is using Windows 7 for which zsh is not available. Please refrain from posting "answers" that in no way help in solving the issue.

Comment: It worked for me! Just keep in mind that you should restarted your VSCode

Answer (score 3):

I needed to kill the terminal in VS Code and restart a new terminal to get npm to show as installed.

Comment: Of course, this would be like the 14th or 15th thing I would try to get it to work. Nevermind the reinstall, reboot, and changing environment PATH variables... LOL, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install npm first, https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm and make sure npm command is accessible using terminal/command prompt.

You can also use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.vscode-npm-script This extension supports running npm scripts defined in the package.json file and validating the installed modules against the dependencies defined in the package.json.

Comment: i am have installed node.js

Comment: Can you access npm using command prompt? You can also verify that PATH is set for npm

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna add an answer just for help others because this question is 2 years old.

If you can run the npm start (NPM SCRIPTS below the Explorer view) but you are not able to launch the command with a shortcut: Then **check npm extension is installed and/or enabled for the current workspace/folder**.

Otherwise vsCode will not be able to run the script and you're going to get a message in a little box like this

```
command 'npm-script.start' not found
```

Maybe the NPM Scripts View below the explorer is not available without the plugin I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting VS code and even my PC didn't work, but after restarting VS code via "reload" (not restart, not refresh) from ctrl+shift+P, then in the top right of the terminal clicking the leftmost button and clicking "kill terminal" then restarting VS code it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and I'm running QubesOS which uses virtualization.
I could manage to get it running until I'd a standalone VM.
That solved my problem.
Just mentioning for the ppl using virtualization like virtual box or VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Since `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux` is now deprecated, the current solution is as follows:

1. Open your preferred `settings.json`
2. Add the following:

   ```json
   "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
      "bash": {
         "path": "bash",
         "icon": "terminal-bash",
         "args": ["-l"]
      }
   },
   "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash"
   ```
3. Restart VSCode

That's it, you're done.